# Javascript: Hide image before page load then Fade image in, working but not quite right

Tags: javascript, image, hide, opacity, fade

first and foremost no jQuery. I accomplished this on jQuery already but I would like to get it running on Javascript.

---

window.onload = function () {

```
var target = document.getElementById('homeimg');
var opacity = 0;
var fader = setInterval(function() {

    if ( opacity <= 100 ) {
        target.style.opacity = ( opacity / 100 );
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(fader);
    }

    opacity += .50;

    }, 100); // End setInterval function
```

} // Ends window.onload

---

when i hid the div in css ( #homeimg {display:none} and {display: hidden} ), the image does not load at all..

the function works but the image is visible for a split second when the page loads, the image then dissappears and then slowly fades in.

i would like to hide the image so that it only fades in.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's because for the first 100 milliseconds, the opacity is the default (1).  After 100 milliseconds, your setInterval function kicks on and starts to fade the image in.

Add this right below the line where you set the `target` variable:

```
target.style.opacity = 0;
```

Or use a CSS style to set the opacity as 0 without JavaScript:

```
#homeimg {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: hi mike, is this how i would add "target.style.opacity = 0;" ? `var target = document.getElementById('homeimg');target.style.opacity = 0; // ***** is this correct? ******fader = setInterval...` i couldnt get the above code to work but setting the opacity: 0 on #homeimg worked perfect

Comment: You would put `target.style.opacity = 0` directly after you set the `target` variable.  Example: http://jsbin.com/cejoxoka/1/edit

Comment: thank you sir. got it working using "target.style.opacity = 0;"... between these two methods, is there a preferred method?